# Need to move a range of numerical files into folders based on filename

Tags: powershell

We have thousands of packets that are scanned each day into a temporary folder and they are named with their packet number. For example: 301949.pdf, 405311.pdf, 481502.pdf, etc.

Our folder structure is built out into folders at the thousand level and subfolders at the hundred level like this:

- Y:\PACKETS\300000\300000-300099
- Y:\PACKETS\300000\300100-300199
- Y:\PACKETS\300000\300200-300299
- Y:\PACKETS\300000\300300-300399
- Y:\PACKETS\300000\300400-300499
- Y:\PACKETS\300000\300500-300599
- Y:\PACKETS\300000\300600-300699
- Y:\PACKETS\300000\300700-300799
- Y:\PACKETS\300000\300800-300899
- Y:\PACKETS\300000\300900-300999
- Y:\PACKETS\400000\400000-400099
- Y:\PACKETS\400000\400100-400199
- Y:\PACKETS\400000\400200-400299
- Y:\PACKETS\400000\400300-400399
- Y:\PACKETS\400000\400400-400499
- Y:\PACKETS\400000\400500-400599
- Y:\PACKETS\400000\400600-400699
- Y:\PACKETS\400000\400700-400799
- Y:\PACKETS\400000\400800-400899
- Y:\PACKETS\400000\400900-400999
- Y:\PACKETS\481000\481400-481499
- Y:\PACKETS\481000\481500-481599
- Y:\PACKETS\481000\481600-481699
- Y:\PACKETS\481000\481700-481799
- Y:\PACKETS\481000\481800-481899
- Y:\PACKETS\481000\481900-481999
- Y:\PACKETS\481000\481000-481099
- Y:\PACKETS\481000\481100-481199
- Y:\PACKETS\481000\481200-481299
- Y:\PACKETS\481000\481300-481399

We need to move each packet into it's correct folder based on it's numerical filename:

For example:

- 301949.pdf needs to go into Y:\PACKETS\301000\301900-301999
- 405311.pdf needs to go into Y:\PACKETS\405000\405300-405399
- 481502.pdf needs to go into Y:\PACKETS\481000\481500-481599

I'm not even sure how to begin to do this but I'm hoping someone here can help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might take the [Tour] and (re-)read the help topic [Ask] to set your expectations on SO.

Comment: so ... what have you tried? what have you looked at? [*grin*] have you tried using `Get-Help` yet? have you tried searching S-O? something like this >>> `[powershell] move files to folder by name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a bit bored, so here you go:

```
$SourceFolder = 'Y:\Temp'     # the temporary folder where the pdf files are
$Destination  = 'Y:\PACKETS'  # just the root folder

# you may want to add '-Recurse' if the temp folder contains subfolders
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter '*.pdf' -File |
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^\d{4,}$' } |    # filenames must be numeric and at least 1000 or more 
    ForEach-Object {
        $packet = [int]$_.BaseName                      # create a numeric value from the file's BaseName
        $level1 = [Math]::Floor($packet / 1000) * 1000  # get the 'thousand' value ( 301949 --> 301000 )
        $level2 = [Math]::Floor($packet / 100) * 100    # get the 'hundred' value  ( 301949 --> 301900 )

        # create the complete path to move the file to
        $target = Join-Path -Path $Destination -ChildPath ('{0}\{1}-{2}' -f $level1, $level2, ($level2 + 99))
        # test if this path exists and if not create it
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $target -PathType Container)) {
            $null = New-Item -Path $target -ItemType Directory
        }
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $target
    }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is AWESOME! Thank you so much. Almost exactly what I need- I'll add the recurse option and then will modify to decide what to do if a file exists already.

Comment: @rsnoble Sorry, totally forgot to put `$level1` folder in the path yesterday.. Fixed now.